# How does Material-UI Button component infer the props for the component passed to `component` prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

Can anyone please explain how Material-UI extends the props of its `Button` component with the props of my component if I pass a specific component in the `component` prop?

```
interface MyLinkProps extends ButtonBaseProps {
  someRandomProp: string
}

const MyLink: React.FC<MyLinkProps> = () => {
  return <div></div>
}

<Button component={MyLink} someRandomProp="random">Something</Button>
```

As in this case, the `Button` component is now aware of the `someRandomProp` prop that belongs to my component; which is being passed to `component` prop on the `Button` component.

I would like to achieve the same effect. I have an Image component which has a prop `component` which I would like to infer the props of the component that is being passed.

For example, if there is something like:

```
<MyImage component={NextImage} {...propsOfNextImage} />
```

Basically, I would like `MyImage` to auto-detect and extend the props of `NextImage`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the type definition of `OverridableComponent` [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/ea22ca9c340f01c3510a60285a9564edcbd2fcc2/packages/mui-material/src/OverridableComponent.d.ts#L10-L10), this one is responsible for merging the props of the [overridable component](https://mui.com/guides/composition/#component-prop) with the original props of the component.

For reference, see how it's used in a MUI component [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e75a347f7dfb0209e53a8997ff53a4fde53f8635/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.d.ts). The first generic type parameter is a type with the following properties:

- `props`: The original props of your component before being merged with the props of the overridable component.
- `defaultComponent`: The default root component if you don't provide any.

```js
import { OverridableComponent } from '@mui/material/OverridableComponent';

interface MyImageProps {
  src: string;
  myCustomProps?: string;
}
interface MyImageTypeMap {
  props: MyImageProps;
  defaultComponent: 'img';
}

const MyImage: OverridableComponent<MyImageTypeMap> = (props) => {
  const RootComponent = props.component || 'img';
  return (
    <RootComponent src={props.src} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </RootComponent>
  );
};
```

### Usage

```
{/* normal component with MyImageProps. The root component is an img element */}
<MyImage src={src} />
{/* component with MyImageProps & ButtonProps. The root component is a Button*/}
<MyImage src={src} component={Button} variant="contained">
  I am actually a button in disguise
</MyImage>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]