# Custom component that extend MUI SvgIcon cannot accept `component` prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, framer-motion

I have a component `Icon` that extends the `SvgIcon` MUI component and its props handling:

`Icon.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';

import { SvgIconProps } from '@mui/material';

import SvgIcon, { Icons } from './svg';

export interface IconProps extends Omit<SvgIconProps, 'color'> {
    icon: Icons;
    color: string;
    size?: number | string;
    height?: number;
    width?: number;
};

const Icon = React.memo(
    ({ icon, color, height, width, size, sx: psx, ...rest }: IconProps) => {
        const Svg = SvgIcon[icon];

        const sx = {
            color,
            height: size ?? height,
            width: size ?? width,
            stroke: 'currentColor',
            fill: 'transparent',
            ...psx,
        };

        return <Svg sx={sx} {...rest} />;
    }
);

export default Icon;
```

It must be used like any MUI `SvgIcon` but you must provide an `icon` prop with a value from an `Icons` enum that is generated:

`svg/index.ts`

```
import React from "react";

import { SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material";
import AddSvg from "./AddSvg";
import Contexte1Svg from "./Contexte1Svg";

export enum Icons {
  ADD = "Add",
  CONTEXTE1 = "Contexte1"
}

type SvgComponents = {
  [key in Icons]: React.FC<SvgIconProps>;
};

const SvgIcon: SvgComponents = {
  [Icons.ADD]: AddSvg,
  [Icons.CONTEXTE1]: Contexte1Svg
};

export default SvgIcon;
```

So our `Icon` component can render the given `icon` with props.

It works as expected but my issue here is with its type definition, i can't achieve to define its type properly. The only issue i have is when i use the [`component`](https://mui.com/api/svg-icon/#main-content) prop on it typescript throw me the following error:

```
 // here i'm trying to use a `framer-motion` component as root component for `SvgIcon`
<Icon
  icon={Icons.CONTEXTE1}
  size={22}
  color="text.hint"
  component={motion.svg}
  variants={fadeOut}
  initial="default"
  animate={isHovered ? 'hover' : 'default'}
/>
```

```
TS2322: Type '{ icon: Icons.CONTEXTE1; size: number; color: string; component: ForwardRefComponent<SVGSVGElement, SVGMotionProps<SVGSVGElement>>; variants: { ...; }; initial: string; animate: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconProps'.   Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconProps'.
```

I've tried so many ways to extends `SvgIconProps` but can't find a way to correctly type this `Icon` component.

[image: Edit [SO] Custom MUI Icon component: component prop]

Comment: use @ts-ignore. I think it's an issue with material ui, where typescript thinks component prop is not exists in many components

Comment: Have a look at the `OverridableComponent` usage [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e75a347f7dfb0209e53a8997ff53a4fde53f8635/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.d.ts). Fixed codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-custom-mui-icon-component-component-prop-forked-ickb5?file=/src/Components/AnimatedIcon/AnimatedIcon.tsx). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484275/9449426) answer for more detail.

Comment: thanks a lot for the workaround!